# Firebase: Get hourly/daily/monthly count

Tags: firebase

I'm new to Firebase and coming from MySQL. I'm not able to wrap my head around this, which is trivial in case of MySQL. I'd like to retrieve number of records (in this case — visits) on either hourly, daily or monthly interval. Each visit is recorded in Firebase as follows (I may have got this wrong as well).

```
{
    "visit": {
      "timestamp": 1414622353610,
      "user": "198"
    },
    "visit": {
      "timestamp": 1414622353680,
      "user": "55"
    },
    "visit": {
      "timestamp": 1414622353710,
      "user": "60"
    }
}
```

How would I go about implementing this in Firebase. I don't find any relevant query methods for the same in the Firebase docs. I'm working with Firebase REST API, so an example using REST would be more helpful.

Comment: Firebase engineer here. Data stores such as Firebase are called NoSQL for a reason. :-)  Often the solution is to denormalize your data structure. You should probably read https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html . This post from Kato also seems pretty relevant: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html#between. Note that Firebase has grown significantly since both of these were written. So even though the concepts are still very much relevant, there may be easier way to implement things with today's Firebase.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did read those articles. However, I could not relate the articles with the problem at hand. How would you go about achieving this with Firebase?

Answer (score 2):

I set up a Firebase with a data structure like the one you showed.

This query will get you the events in a certain minute:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://<yours>.firebaseio.com/'),
    startTime = 1427138419385,
    endTime = startTime + 60 * 1000;
ref
    .orderByChild('timestamp')
    .startAt(startTime)
    .endAt(endTime)
    .once('value', function(snap) {
       console.log('There are ', messages.numChildren(), ' messages in range', snap.val());
    });
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qg5hmong/

Note that this code is a fairly direct adaption from this blog post: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html#between. The only difference is that we can now use `orderByChild`, which didn't yet exist at the time that Kato wrote the blog post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However this just returns the records found between the start and end time. I'm instead looking for a count of records at an interval of lets say 1 hour between the start and end time. In SQL for 12 PM to 4 PM, I would essentially get an array like [4, 10, 5, 20]. Value at each index represents the count of records separated by an interval of an hour.

Comment: See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/numchildren.html for how to get a count. Aside from that, it seems you have a good grasp of your requirements. I suggest you go ahead and use the code above as a starting point to implement them.

Comment: I believe what you are suggesting is to that I need to make 4 queries to fetch hourly count for four hours and likewise 24 queries for 24 hours? Each query with start time as the start of the hour and the end time as the end of the hour. Correct?

Comment: That would be one way of doing it. Alternatively you store it in the hourly format that you need the data in. That would make data writes more expensive (and possibly duplicate some data), but reading it would be dead-cheap.

Comment: Frank has provided you all the tools you need here. It's starting to sound more like you want him to write your code than answer the question. Some assembly required and all.

Comment: @Kato I'm not exactly looking for Frank to write the code for me. I have read through the blog posts mentioned and Firebase documentation. Not even one place I could find relevant stuff that's so trivial on MySQL. I did not expect to make 24 calls to Firebase to retrieve hourly count for a day or 30 calls for a month, when same could be done with a single query on MySQL. People coming from relational databases have to unlearn things and understand the NoSQL way and that definitely is not about someone else writing the code for you.

Comment: @John:"what is the best?" or "where do I start?" questions are really difficult to answer on a Q&A site like StackOverflow. Normally those get closed as "too broad" fairly quickly. In this case I created a snippet to show one way you could implement one of your use-cases. This is probably a good moment for you to take the sample I created and start working on your use-cases with it. That will probably lead to more questions, but those should be more concrete.